# Webpack plugin: How to dynamically add a loader to a module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing a Webpack plugin. During module resolution, this plugin should dynamically add a specific loader for *some modules*, but not for all.

My idea right now is to tap into `normal-module-factory`'s `after-resolve` event. There, I could modify the array `data.loaders`. Some debugging showed me that this array contains objects of the form `{ loader: string, options: object | undefined }`.

I couldn't find any documentation on modifying per-module loaders on the fly. So I'm wondering:

- Is this the right approach?
- Some (but not all) existing `loaders` entries contain an additional property `ident`, looking like this: `'ref--0-0'`. When should I set this property, and using what value?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether it's the best solution, but this code appears to work:

```
class MyPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('normal-module-factory', normalModuleFactory => {
      normalModuleFactory.plugin('after-resolve', (data, callback) => {
        data.loaders.push({
          loader: ..., // Path to loader
          options: {}
        });
        callback(null, data);
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = MyPlugin;
```

Regarding the extra `ident` property: Webpack needs to be able to compare loader options. By default, it does this by calling `JSON.stringify()` on the options object, then comparing the resulting strings. By adding an `ident` property, you can explicitly specify a string representation of the options object. For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49006233/52041.

Answer (score 3):

I was attempting to solve a similar problem, and wanted to add a loader only for specific files identified elsewhere in a plugin. My solution goes as follows:

loader.js

```
module.exports = function loader(content) {
  return mySpecialTransformation(content);
};
```

plugin.js

```
const path = require('path');

class MyPluginName {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('MyPluginName', compilation => {
      compilation.hooks.normalModuleLoader.tap('MyPluginName', (loaderContext, module) => {
        if (myModuleCondition(module)) {
          module.loaders.unshift({
            loader: path.resolve(__dirname, 'loader.js'), // Path to loader
            options: {}
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Note that I've used unshift rather than push to add the loader - I'm still in the development stage so I could be wrong, but my current understanding is that I would want my loader to run after all 'standard' loaders which may well be transpiling typescript, etc. I believe that loaders are then applied from right to left. Depending on what you're doing this may not be important.

Comment: For anyone using Webpack 5 or newer, beware that `normalModuleLoader` has moved to `NormalModule.getCompilationHooks(compilation).loader` instead. See [this docs page](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/#normalmoduleloader).

Comment: If you want examples, check the test this case: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/1f13ff9fe587e094df59d660b4611b1bd19aed4c/test/configCases/loaders/pr-14384/PluginWithLoader.js and this fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/75771396/470117