# Webpack loaders: Are options considered when caching?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing a Webpack loader that should be cacheable. The [documentation for `this.cacheable`](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#this-cacheable) says:

> A cacheable loader must have a deterministic result, when inputs and dependencies haven't changed.

Now I wonder: Do the loader's options count as "input" in this sense?

Assume I have a Webpack build that uses a loader with options `{ foo: 1 }` on a module. In the next compilation, it uses the same loader on the same module, but with options `{ foo: 2 }`. Will the output from the first compilation be re-used, or will Webpack (correctly) realize that the loader's options have changed and thus re-load the module?

Assuming that Webpack *does* compare the `options` objects, how are they compared? By reference? Using a deep comparison? The comparison logic would dictate what types of data I can safely use as loader options.

Answer (score 1):

**Short version:**

Webpack identifies a module via its `request` string. This string contains the file path as well as the paths *and options* of all involved loaders. This effectively means that changing the options on one loader will result in a different request string, so the previous load result *will not* be re-used.

**Long version:**

Request strings are "!"-separated and are created by [this code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.0.1/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js#L228).

Consider this request string:

```
"/Users/wolf/dev/webpack-test/test-loader.js!/Users/wolf/dev/webpack-test/patch-loader.js??ref--0-0!/Users/wolf/dev/webpack-test/src/foo.js"
```

This means (from right to left) that file `/Users/wolf/dev/webpack-test/src/foo.js` is to be loaded using first the loader `/Users/wolf/dev/webpack-test/patch-loader.js` with options `ref--0-0`, then the loader `/Users/wolf/dev/webpack-test/test-loader.js` without any options.

The relevant question, now, is how Webpack serializes the loaders' options when creating the request string. The answer can be found [in this code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.0.1/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js#L21):

Let `loaderData` be an object of this form:

```
{
  loader: string, // Path to loader
  options: string | object | null | undefined,
  ident: string | null | undefined
}
```

- If `loaderData.options` is a string, it is used as-is.
- Otherwise, if `loaderData.ident` is truthy, this value is used.
- Otherwise, `loaderData.options` is stringified using `JSON.stringify`.

It appears that when loaders are [specified statically](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule), Webpack knows that their options won't change. So `RuleSet.normalizeRule()` assigns them fixed `ident` properties. This is what happened in the example above with `ref--0-0`.

One key insight here is that loader options should be rather simple objects so that calling `JSON.stringify` on them doesn't lose any information. Otherwise, Webpack may inadvertently re-use a cached result that used different loader options. Alternatively, you can explicitly set `loaderData.ident` to a string that uniquely identifies the options (such as a hash code).

Answer (score 0):

If you change the loader's inputs then you're essentially creating a new instance of it so it should not use the cache from the loader with different options.

If you look here, it looks like it's just setting a flag that says whether to request cacheable or not and it's up to you to cache results. It's always going to call your loader no matter what. https://github.com/webpack/loader-runner/blob/master/lib/LoaderRunner.js#L270

Comment: That was my hope also, but I couldn't find any documentation or locate the relevant source code. Can you shed any light on the exact behavior (see my questions)?

Comment: If you want to see the loader logic, it's in here: https://github.com/webpack/loader-runner/blob/master/lib/LoaderRunner.js

Comment: Also, a good series to read to get a handle on webpack is: https://medium.com/webpack/the-contributors-guide-to-webpack-part-1-a0410cc82ca4. There are 4 parts...

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing to do is probably just to experiment and see if your config changes cause it to cache or not. It should be pretty easy to tell just with a few log statements.

Comment: If you look here, it looks like it's just setting a flag that says whether to request cacheable or not and it's up to you to cache results. It's always going to call your loader no matter what. https://github.com/webpack/loader-runner/blob/master/lib/LoaderRunner.js#L270